# Question should be reopened without edits

Tags: discussion, reopen-closed

Consider:

*[Why is Person::Impl undefined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76247529/why-personimpl-is-undefined)*

I assume the user, who closed it, did it without reading it, simply pattern matching the headline to old knowledge, because the OP's problem is absolutely not answered by the link.

I'd do it myself, but I don't have sufficient reputation points yet.

Comment: I've not even opened the question and I can assure you that there needs to be an edit. The title does not communicate at all what the issue is.

Comment: Have you read past the accepted answer? There are [some answers from after 2020](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=inquestion%3a12573816%20is%3aa&searchOn=3), and [3 answers containing 'module'](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=inquestion%3A12573816+is%3Aa+module). Otherwise, you may consider to post the solution on the canonical dupe instead.

Comment: Also, if you disagree with the duplicate target, does that still mean that there is not a single other duplicate on the entire site for this?

Comment: @AndrewT. I do in fact know how to use ctrl-f, those usages of "module" are in the old sense of a dll file.

Comment: @VLAZ - quite possible, but then *that* should be the closing reason so the poor guy has a chance to fix what should be fixed, rather than this arbitrary dismissal that has nothing to do with the problem.

Comment: The dupe target can be swapped easily. Requiring a reopen just to be reclosed is a waste of everybody's time.

Comment: @VLAZ Have you found a dupe target that actually answers the question for OP then?

Comment: @SRNissen no. And it's not really my business to do so. You've brought it up to meta, I'm giving meta feedback. If *you* want something to be done for the question why don't *you* do it? What investment do I have in all of this?

Comment: @VLAZ I wrote in OP why I didn't reopen it myself: I don't have the rep for it. Or did you mean - why don't I find a dupe target? In that case, because I do not believe it exists, I thought you already had one since you so confidently asserted the target could easily be swapped.

Comment: "*I thought you already had one since you so confidently asserted the target could easily be swapped.*" it can be swapped from system perspective. If a question is closed as a duplicate, then gold badge holders and mods can simply edit the targets. The alternative is to reopen (requiring three votes) and then re-close (requiring another three votes) which is a lot more work than swapping a duplicate target.

Comment: Only if a dupe target exists, otherwise it is significantly harder.

Comment: *"I'd do it myself but I don't have the rep yet."* Do *what* exactly? You have more than enough rep to suggest an edit to the question (as any one can), and choose to send it to the review queue, and no one can unilaterally reopen a question based on reputation.

Comment: Mentioning/targeting specific users is frowned upon here! Also note, that I already did cast a reopen vote, after correcting the tags to be more specific. Now added the broad c++ tag again, let's see if that helps.

Comment: And now it is closed again, with the same invalid reason, and slated for deletion.

Comment: The OP accepted the duplicate this time, @n.m. , so I wouldn't say it's "invalid". Clearly the answers on the other question provided them with a solution.

Comment: @ThomA I rather doubt it. The other question is about linker errors. This question is not.

Answer (score 9):

As the person who actually provided an answer to this question:

I know that this is a new feature with almost no implementation support and knowledge of the feature in the community at this point is limited. I was however quite surprised at people's willingness to throw downvotes and close votes at this question nonetheless.

I do think that there is valid technical reasons why this particular question should not be closed as a duplicate and similar questions should also not be closed because of potential duplicates that are unrelated to C++20 modules.

The way how type declarations are propagated in C++20 Modules is sufficiently different from the traditional header/source file approach that closing such questions as duplicates to non-modules questions is problematic, even if, as in this case, there exists a clear analogous situation in the header-based world. I would personally caution against closing modules-related questions like this, as it is very easy to accidentally falsely assume that behavior is similar to what we know from the pre-modules C++20 world.

The whole distinction of visibility vs. reachability in a modules context being my primary worry here, as this changes significantly in what situations users will experience particular kinds of errors.

The form of the question is fine and contains a complete example that is sufficient to reproduce and understand the problem. I don't feel that this needs substantial edits before being reopened.

Comment: Are you saying the question should be reopened or it should stay closed? This question is about discussing the closing / reopening of the linked question. I don't see your answer addressing that directly

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat I think that there is valid technical reasons why the question should not be closed as a duplicate and similar questions should also not be closed because of potential duplicates that are unrelated to C++20 modules.

Comment: This is starting to be a trend. Another question closed as a dupe of a pretty big catch-all canonical. "The answer is in there SOMEWHERE, good luck fishing it out yourself". And in this case the answer isn't even in there yet apparently :/

Comment: @ComicSansMS can you please [edit] and make that more clear? As someone who is not an SME the point you put forth in the answer is a bit vague / difficult to parse. Maybe something like "I believe this post should not be closed because the duplicate target is about ... whereas the post is about ...." would be suitable, in which case an edit to the question to clarify that will also probably help

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat Edited my answer to make that point more clear. I hope this will make my argument more understandable.

Comment: I'd say the question doesn't require editing *now*, after OP edited it, providing more details. Not sure how important this distinction is. The error message, which the question now contains, is very important, and would prevent the initial confusion. Thanks for answering anyway!

Comment: (I presume you didn't [change the user name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76247529/why-is-personimpl-undefined#comment134469517_76247529) in the middle of all this(?).)

Comment: @PeterMortensen No, I didn't.  I have no idea either who Marc is.

Answer (score -7):

> Question should be re-opened without edits

I'll treat this like an actual question. Probably the answer is no: your question should be re-opened with edits (I didn't check in depth).

I guess the user who closed your question got confused because the question didn't contain enough information. You actually provide that information in comments! So just edit it into the question, and maybe people will reopen your question.

Comment: It's not my question. I was researching an answer when the question was closed as a dupe. Research that was easy to start because the question is super obvious, though not a minimal example.

Comment: But you do have more information on the problem?

Comment: I stopped when I could no longer add an answer, so no.

Comment: I mean, "Tried solutions X and Y; didn't help, so this problem is new and not like what is described in the link". This is valuable information which you have. It makes the question clearer and worth reopening.